# Tire gem: is document exists in index?

Tags: ruby, rspec, elasticsearch

How, with [tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire) gem, check in `rspec` test: Is document exists in ElasticSearch index?

Example:

```
#model
class Car
  include Mongoid::Document
  include include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  #...
end

#spec
record = Car.first
record.tire.exist_in_index?.should be_true #wrong code
```

Or maybe any other workarounds.

Comment: is something wrong with your code, or what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @phoet thats just an example, I want to know how to check: is document stored in the ElasticSearch index.

Comment: that depends very much on the way you use tire. ie when using `Tire::Persistance` you should be able to check `persisted?` on the model

Comment: @phoet I edited question, for more information.

Comment: you can use this method: https://github.com/karmi/retire/blob/master/lib/tire/index.rb#L347

Comment: @phoet Good idea, that works: `record.tire.index.retrieve("can", o.id.to_s)` Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create custom matcher:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_in_search_index do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    !!actual.tire.index.retrieve(actual.class.name.underscore, actual.id.to_s)
  end
end

#...
record.should be_in_search_index
```